# Restrict access to system functions for C++ library at compile time

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linkage

I am on the way to implement some kind of plugin system for C++ application. I'd call it volatile. The plugin is a shared library `*.so`.

#### requirement

Do not allow any calls to system.

#### the problem

Since a plugin SO loaded by Application it will inherit all rights and accesses. We do not trust Plugin.

#### the idea

From a given C++ source code of the Plugin compile SO with special GCC/CLang flags, like `--do-not-link-filesystem`, `--do-not-link-pthread`. So if that code tries to access system resources it will fail at compile time. This gives the best warranty.
Plugin can call to interface provided by Application.
STL `<vector>`, `<algorithm>` and `<boost/template-only-headers>` should still be available.

#### idea 2

Run ApplicationHelper to load Plugin.so in a restricted container or/and run as user with restricted rights. *looks hard*

### the question

- Is it possible to implement idea 1 – restrict access at compile time?
- Tell please how to implement idea 2 in linux, espesially Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you asking about system calls or calls to `std::system()` - they are not the same thing.

Comment: std::system, and fopen, and mkdir, and mkfifo,  so restrict any access to filesystem and kernel.

Comment: You want idea 2. do-not-link-{pthread,filesystem} is nonsense. Easily circumventable (the library can implement its own threading). With a separate executable you can restrict filesystem access via uids and limit system calls via seccomp, and there's various ways to do IPC.

Comment: sounds like you are trying to write a web server and emulate the blocking of calls to sync APIs

Comment: idea 3 - instead of allowing arbitrary machine code in plugins, instead require "plugins" to be written in some embedded scripting language which could then be run in a sandboxed environment?  (Note that even if you disallow linking to system call wrappers from glibc in plugins, it would still be easy for plugins to compile in `syscall` instructions directly in assembler...)

Comment: No, I would say that is not possible.

Comment: Why don't you trust a plugin that you have the sourcecode for? Also, loading a SO means you have that SO in your memory space and it can do pretty much anything it wants there. The only guaranteed barrier is that of the process, which the OS enforces. For that, check out SE Linux or similar sandboxes.

Comment: Sounds like you may be looking for [sandboxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)).

Comment: I want to give ability to rule the machine in C++. There is good service written in C++. I imagine the service compiles C++ code (say job file) and loads compiled SO, then runs job.

Comment: You cannot do that, the language is compiled, the plugin could bypass any call to any library by perform system calls through asm statements.

Comment: Yes. We use some scripting languages for that, and service has REST API. But I consider to write job in C++, so asked this question. *Thank you, guys for participation.*

Comment: Isn't it possible to restrict compiling ASM instructions? Only Pure C++!

Comment: idea 1 is nonsense, having native code compiled by _someone_ you may have anything inside it.. even code that would invade into your application (it's an .so!) and do anything its creator wanted. And even without asm, you can do  most of stuff using C++ and intrinstics. Or shell code :P You seem 
 do not realize how close to metal C++ is. One of most used approaches is to use Mono or LUA or something like that to allow user write plugins. SO they can only use offered API.

Comment: This is impossible without aggressive sandboxing and C++ offers nothing to help you here. C++ code can do *anything* by design. You can't restrict it. Consider: Sandboxing *JavaScript* in the browser is extremely hard. Sandboxing arbitrary C++ is basically impossible unless you run that code in a special container, not part of your main process.

Comment: (continues after tadman)  ... unless you write your own translator. e.g. C++ subset dialect  -> RESTFUL API. Catch? It's astronomically hard to do and alot of support required to work out all kinks. Look at what Linden Lab was doing with their ObjectC subset language compiled into Mono code. It took them ten years to make it more or less decent.

Comment: @tadman actually there is project that allows client-side sandboxing of C++ within web browser, but it's not precompiled one, it's used like a javascript, not arbitrary.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I guess Emscripten -> Webassembly -> JavaScript sandbox is a valid solution here, but yikes.

Comment: @tadman "Sir is a notorious connoisseur of perversions", haha. Yeah, I thought of emscripten.